# How to use a certificate with ssl to connect to webservice via https://

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am a newbie in this area... How to use a certificate with ssl to connect to webservice via https:// ? What are the neccesary steps to follow. I already have a signed certificate which is already installed on the remote server.

Any idea?

I would like to do this in c#. Should I use OpenSSL.NET ?

Kind regards,

Eric Karijo

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C# , the `HttpWebRequest` class has a `clientCertificates` collection property.  In short, you add your certificate to this collection before sending the request.

You would want to do some flow along the lines of

- Install the certificate in your machine keystore (or really however you want to store/distribute client certs

in C#:

- create a webrequest
- load cert from keystore
- add cert to clientCertificates
  collection send request

So (sorry if this isn't 100%):

```
// instanstiate request
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

// access keystore, find your cert
X509Store keystore = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
X509CertificateCollection certs = keystore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "Name Of Cert", true);

// add cert to request object
req.ClientCertificates = certs;


// continue with preparing the request and submitting
```